# Delete the "dell" tag?

Tags: support, tags

There are only 5 questions tagged with the [dell](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dell) tag, all of them about Dell monitors. Those 5 questions are also tagged [monitors](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitors).

From a photographic context, "Dell" doesn't have any meaning — they don't produce any cameras, notable photo printers, lenses, etc. Of all of the major (and smaller but notable) monitor manufacturers, only [samsung](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung) has its own tag. But all of the Samsung questions are about cameras (none of them are also tagged [monitors](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monitors)).

Seems to me a rather useless tag. Can we kill it?

Comment: Do you think the tag is actually causing a problem? If not, this falls into a bit of a "meh" category for me - I'm sure we've got lots of not particularly useful tags, but there aren't enough minutes in the day to deal with every one of them.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I doubt it's causing any problems at all. It was just something I noticed. I'm just trying to get a sense of the protocol when it comes to tag cleanup. Is it objectionable if I just single-handedly go through those 5 answers and zap the "dell" tag from them? Or should I wait for consensus before doing so? Won't the tag get deleted automatically after a certain time if no questions are using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say if the questions actually are specific to photographic workflow with Dell monitors, leave the tag. If it's just kind of randomly attached because someone's monitor or computer happens to be from Dell, leave it. I don't think it causes any harm.

Comment: Fair enough. For some reason I thought the tag space was a lot smaller than it was. I went back and checked... yeah, there's a lot there. Worrying about this dinky tag is a waste of time!